# Using whitespace in Ruby code (the ternary operator)

Tags: ruby, whitespace, ternary-operator

Considering this piece of code:

```
values = ["one", "two", "", "four"]

values.each do |value|
puts value.empty? ? "emptyness" : "#{value} is #{value.length}"
end
```

is it possible in Ruby 1.8.7 to format the ternary operator indenting the operands? Something like:

```
puts value.empty?
    ? "emptyness" 
    : "#{value} is #{value.length}"
```

but this one obviously won't work.

Comment: Generally, you should use the ternary operator only for really short expressions. If you feel you need to use multiple lines, it is probably a better idea to use a full `if [...] else [...] end` to make it more readable and explicit.

Comment: I disagree that it should fit on a line if you're using the ternary operator. The less temporary variables you use the better. Your code will be more readable in left-to-right fashion, rather than having to go further down to find out why you are doing all the intermediate conditional logic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the character `\` to split the command into newlines.

This will work:

```
values = ["one", "two", "", "four"]

values.each do |value|
   puts value.empty? \
     ? "emptyness" \
     : "#{value} is #{value.length}"
end
```

Also, you can't have any space after the `\` character or a syntax error will be raised.

Answer (score 6):

The way to do this using Ruby itself with no escapes is to have Ruby know that it is waiting for more information

```
puts value.empty?  ?
  "emptyness" :
  "#{value} is #{value.length}"
```

The reason for this is Ruby sees the parts of the ternary and knows that something more is needed to complete the statement.

Using parenthesis in the OP's code would not work, the statements would still be partial, and Ruby would not know what to do with the ? and : on the next line.

Of course, you don't really need the ternary:

```
values = ["one", "two", "", "four"]

values.each do |value|
  puts value.empty? && "emptyness" ||
    "#{value} is #{value.length}"
end
```

Comment: Alternatively, OP could use parenthesis.

Comment: I've always find this way less expressive. It's not immediately visible that the following lines are part of the operator, but good to know.

Comment: You are right, at least the question mark needs to be on the same line (when not using escapes). That said, it's still a bad idea to split a ternary into multiple lines in the first place :)

Answer (score 2):

When the ternary operator needs to be split into multiple lines, it may be time to use an *if* instead:

```
puts if value.empty?
       "emptyness"
     else
       "#{value} is #{value.length}"
     end
```

This works because *if*, like any other expression in Ruby, has a result.  That result is the result of either the *then* or the *else* section, whichever got executed (and if the condition is false and there is no *else* section, then the result of the *if* is nil).

Comment: True, but not the question asked.

Comment: @vgoff, The OP's unfamiliarity with Ruby syntax suggests that the OP may not be aware of some of Ruby's more subtle points.  Since this one--that _if_ is an expression with a value--leads to another (and arguably superior) way of solving the problem, it's germane.

Comment: I would find it strange to ask questions about the ternary before becoming aware of an if statement.  I assumed no unfamiliarity for the OP with Ruby syntax, but rather how expressions are terminated.  Rather, asking about Ruby's more subtle point about line endings would suggest they are familiar with the syntax.  Though I do agree the point the syntax is related.